# Subquery returns more than 1 row in Django while connecting models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to get authorName whenever someone search for a book and yeah I have tried many to many but it is very confusing and after researching some things I got to a view which I thought should work fine but it is returning an error "1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'"  here are some of the relevant code:

**Models**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Books(models.Model):
    bid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    bname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bdescription = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bname

class Authors(models.Model):
    aid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    aname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    adescription = models.TextField( blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.aname+"\n"


class Bookauth(models.Model):
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='bid', blank=True, null=True)
    aid = models.ForeignKey(Authors, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='aid', blank=True, null=True)
```

**Views** for what I thought was right

```
def authbook(request):

    s = Authors.objects.all()
    r = Books.objects.filter(bookauth__aid = s).values()
    return HttpResponse(r)
```

Comment: I tried JsonResponse too for getting "More than one row" in a dict but same error.

Comment: Why haven't you used a [many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)?

Comment: @KlausD. I tried using it but didn't understood any of it.

Comment: You should go through the topic again. It is important and solves your actual problem.